# Make a div blink on setinterval

Tags: jquery, css, setinterval

Once every second a single div is supposed to blink. right know it changes the color but i cant figure out how to change it back to the original color within 1 sec. I want each random div to display green on window open than yellow than back to green. then go to the next random div

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var $div
    for(var i = 0; i < 30 ; i++){
        $div = $("<div>", {class: "a lime" })
        $(".container").append($div)
    }
    console.log($(".a").eq(1))
    var random
    setInterval(function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < $(".a").length && (i % 4 == 0); i ++){
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(".a").length)
        var saved  = random;

            // if(i % 2 == ){
                if($(".a").eq(saved).hasClass("lime")){
                    //!!!make it so that after changing to yellow so that it changes to green.
                         lime class is green!!!
                    $(".a").eq(saved).removeClass("lime").addClass("yellow")
                }else if ($(".a").eq(saved).hasClass("yellow")){
                    $(".a").eq(saved).removeClass("yellow").addClass("lime")
                }
                // $(".a").eq(saved).toggleClass("yellow")
                // $(".a").eq(saved).toggleClass("lime")
            // }


    }
    }, 1000)
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jadendreamer/Nx4qS/30/ this might be useful

Comment: quick look at that fiddle. shows that it just adds and removes the same class. I need to keep tracks of the classes because there might be diff colors. in the fiddle the original style of el is default. my original will have custom styles. i want to figure out how in the case after adding the class yellow to remove the class yellow and add class green. i dont think its possible in the type of way i did it because it will always be green. there should be like a callback after adding the yellow class in the first condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

HTML

```
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}

.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var $divs = $('div');
var totalDivs = $divs.length;

function blinkRandomDiv() {
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * totalDivs));
    var randomDiv = $divs.eq(random);

    $divs.removeClass('yellow').addClass('green');

    randomDiv.toggleClass('green yellow');
}

setInterval(blinkRandomDiv, 1000);
```

With fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39mfrf6m/8/.

Comment: cool. so on every iteration your removing from all the divs the class `yellow` and adding the class `green`. but for the specific random div your toggling the class.... but I never used two classes like this in toggle class. is it basically saying if it's green change the class to yellow?

Comment: Best recommendation is to read the toggleClass documentation http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/. It's saying if you have either of these classes turn them off, if you don't add them. Because we know they're all green at this point, it'll only add the yellow class and remove the green class.